Contradiction in Jeremiah 32 and 37?
It seems like the book of Jeremiah is written out of chronological order, but I'm still able to follow along just fine. However, chapter 32 tells the story of him buying a field while confined in the prison courtyard, and chapter 37 tells the story of him being confined in the courtyard after a misunderstanding when he went to go claim that field. Did he buy the field twice, are there two fields, was he imprisoned twice, or do these stories contradict eachother? I'm sure I missed something, hopefully someone here can help me figure it out.

It is true that the Book of Jeremiah, as we now have it, is not all in chronological order.  Ezekiel is the same.

Jeremiah isn't in chronological order. Chapter 37 starts with Zedekiah taking the throne, in chapter 32 it's already the tenth year of Zedekiah.
Chapter 37, unless I'm missing something, says nothing about Jeremiah going to claim the field he purchased. Verse 12 just says "Then Jeremiah went forth out of Jerusalem to go into the land of Benjamin, to separate himself thence in the midst of the people" - nothing about purchasing land, it sounds more like he's trying to hide from enemies in Jerusalem (edit: it seems the translation is disputed). It might seem like a coincidence that both chapter 32 and 37 refer to Benjamin, but it really isn't. Jeremiah was from Anathoth in the land of Benjamin (see 1:1), and it's hardly surprising that his cousin was from the same city. When Jeremiah decides to leave Jerusalem, it's only natural that he goes back to his home town. Therefore there's no contradiction, the chronology is apparently as follows:

Zedekiah comes to the throne (37:1-2)
Jeremiah prophecies against Zedekiah and Jerusalem (37:3-10)
Jeremiah leaves Jerusalem and tries to return to his home in Anathoth (37:11-12)
Jeremiah is arrested and imprisoned in the house of Jonathan the scribe (37:13-16)
Zedekiah calls for Jeremiah and has him moved to the court of the prison (37:17-21)
While in the court of the prison, the word of the Lord comes to Jeremiah, telling him to buy his cousin's field, which is also in Anathoth (chapter 32).


I see ch37 vv1-2 as a general statement which doesn't identify the date of the rest of the chapter.

@StephenDisraeli I half agree, it places the rest of the chapter in Zedekiah's reign but no more. But it resets the clock, so to speak, it makes it clear that this isn't just a continuation of the earlier story where Zedekiah has already been ruling for 10 years. Especially considering that the previous two chapters jump back to the days of Jehoiakim, I don't see how we can reasonably argue that this is supposed to be chronological.

The rest of the chapter shows the Babylonian siege, existing in ch32, being interrupted by the Egyptian move. On the assumption that the portion of ch37 is the field of ch32, I think the chronology works out rather well. In my own answer, I have drawn attention to the fact that the two bouts of imprisonment begin in different ways.

@StephenDisraeli But that is an assumption that I don't really see a strong justification for. Note that there are differing translations of this verse - I don't know if that reflects a difference in the underlying text, some make no reference to receiving anything, others refer to an inheritance (which would also presumably be in Anathoth but wouldn't be the field of chapter 32). I also don't see that there's any contradiction between the two accounts of the imprisonment. Chapter 37 gives more details but both amount to Zedekiah putting him in the court of the prison.

Having said that, while I'm not convinced that your interpretation is correct, it does show that there are at least a couple plausible ways that these texts can fit together and there's no reason to see them as a contradiction, I've given you an upvote.

As a student of history, I too get frustrated by the muddled chronology.
As I see it, the answer is "two imprisonments".
On my own analysis, ch32 is the first imprisonment, in the early stages of the Babylonian siege. On that occasion, the imprisonment comes from the king (v3) and is prompted by his preaching, understood by the authorities as pro-Babylonian. It confines him to one space, viz. the court of the guard, but it appears that nobody is prevented from coming in to visit him. That is how he is able to conduct the buisness about the field purchase..
But there is a short period when he is released from imprisonment. The words of ch33 are introduced by the statement that they were given to Jeremiah "while he was still shut up in the court of the guard".But in ch34 he appears to have been released. The Lord is able to instruct him to go and speak to the king (v2), and he is probably involved in promoting the covenant to free the local slaves, which the city made and then broke in that chapter.
Chs 35 and 36 are a "flashback" to the reign of Jehoiakim, probably set there to explain why the Babylonian siege is taking place.
At the beginning of ch37, the Babylonian army has moved away in order to stand ready for the approach of the Egyptian army, though Jeremiah is warned in vv6-8 that they will soon be coming back. "Not yet in prison" in v4 needs to be read as "not yet put back in prison". Jeremiah tries to make use of this extra freedom of movement to see to the field he has bought (v12). This prompts a second arrest, which is not the king's doing. This is really the private initiative of a powerful political faction, so he ends up in dungeon cells within the house of Jonathan the secretary, where he is probably being starved. Only when he gets the chance to appeal directly to the king is he returned to the court of the guard.
In ch38, we see that his imprisonment there does not prevent him from preaching his message "to all the people", who must have been coming in to see him. So his enemies are allowed to send him down into the cistern of Malchiah, located within that court. Again, he would probably have died there, but Ebed-Melech is given permission to pull him up to the surface again. Apart from that interlude, he remains in the court of the guard until he is removed by the Babylonians and finally released by them (ch40).
